# Cannot install Ubuntu 12.04.2 on Windows 8 in legacy mode, no partitions detected in gparted?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I want to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. Windows 8 is installed in legacy mode (not UEFI). When I use a Ubuntu 12.04.2 cd to install, it does not detect Windows 8. If I click on custom installation, it says that the entire hard drive is free space, i.e. does not detect any partitions.

I also loaded a Gparted iso, and that also failed to detect any partitions. fdisk -l returned nothing.

Any ideas on why windows 8 is not detected by Ubuntu / no partitions are detected by gparted?

PS. Please explain things simply if possible. I'm a linux noob ...

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your partition table is damaged. There's a good chance that my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts) program can fix the problem, but I can't promise that. You can either run it from Windows (using an Administrator Command Prompt window) or by using a Linux disc in its live CD mode. (IIRC, FixParts is included in the Ubuntu `gdisk` package, so you may need to install that.)